# Searching for some users on SO returns a list sorted by incorrect order

Tags: bug, search

Some username search results are not correctly sorted by highest reputation on Stack Overflow.

#### Steps to reproduce:

1. Visit https://stackoverflow.com/users
2. In the *Users* Search Box enter the following username for example; `RobC`
3. The list of users returned is currently as follows:

   [image: SO Search results listing usernames RobC]

   **Note:**

   - User *RobC* listed in sixth position from the top, i.e. the one at the bottom in the screenshot above, has a weekly reputation increase of `88`.
   - The first five listed users all have a weekly reputation of `0`.

#### Expected Result:

- Users with a higher reputation to be listed above/before users with a lower reputation.
- Given the scenario provided in the aforementioned section, I expect user *RobC* who is currently listed in sixth position from the top, i.e. the one at the bottom in the screenshot above, who has the highest weekly reputation increase of `88` to be listed at the top.

#### Additional Info

- Regardless of whether the *Reputation* is sorted by either; *week*, *month*, *quarter*, *year*, or *all* - the list returns in the incorrect sort order.
- Other examples of usernames (randomly chosen and at time of writing) that also show the incorrect sort order are; `Peter`, and `Sarah`. However many usernames do seem to return correctly sorted.
- This incorrect sorting started to occur approx 3-4+ weeks ago.

Comment: Users with the same name are sorted by userid not reputation.

Comment: @DavidPostill - Correct, at present users are sorted by _userid_. However, that has not been the case for the last _n_ years - instead users have been sorted by reputation (highest first). Is this newly introduced change of logic, i.e. sorting by _userid_ instead of reputation, now by-design or a bug?

Comment: Would seem to make sense to do what is the best for performance, or have some kind of social relevance algo a la Facebook.  Or have it be based on context (tags you frequent? which is kind of like social context I guess).  Or allow sort params to be chosen.  user id seems to be really arbitrary, and honestly so is reputation.  Although realistically I guess it makes sense you would care more about people who are high ranked more than some random newbies.