# Sorting on user page is broken

Tags: bug, sorting, users-page

If I go to the users page, select "Reputation" and "all", and then type something in the search box, the results are not sorted by reputation:

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, there doesn't seem to be any rhyme or reason to the order of the users. I'm trying to see the users named "Peter" with the highest total reputation, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly.

Comment: This one is very frustrating to me. Unfortunately, it was reported before and was deemed bydesign. Apparently, users with the same name are sorted by id rather than reputation (for some reason). I'll try to find a link later.

Comment: I remember I used to to do this often years ago and it used to work as expected. I wonder why they decided to break it.

Comment: Maybe [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347964/)

Comment: @bobble There's no answer to that question, so no, of course not.

Comment: That was just an auto-generated comment ... the earlier version, 'Possible duplicate of' would have worked much better in this case. It *is* the same question.